# error when require_once() link out of subdirectory

Tags: php, warnings, fatal-error, include-path

I am trying to require_once() a file that is in a folder located in my root... I am requiring this file from a file that is in another sub-folder of my root.

- Root

  - includes

    - include_all.php
  - my

    - question_history.php

This is my/question_history.php:

```
 <?php require_once("./includes/include_all.php"); ?>
```

I am getting these errors:

> Warning:
>   require_once(./includes/include_all.php) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AnswerTree2/my/question_history.php
>   on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required './includes/include_all.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear')
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AnswerTree2/my/question_history.php
>   on line 3

I am kinda new to keeping files in different folders as I used to just put everything in root folder. bad practice i know. but anyway hope this is enough detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right code would be:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/include_all.php"); ?>
```

The error comes, becouse `./` requires the file to be in the same folder, so your code would require the `includes` folder be in the `my` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `./` is the current directory. Try `/includes/include_all.php` instead.

Comment: Maybe PHP has no privileges to access this file? Have you granted them on file creation? See also __DIR__ as GeoffK suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the magic constants, might be helpful. Using __DIR__ for example might be useful: [PHP Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)